# How to pivot a dataframe on a two level header in R code

Tags: r, pivot, tidyverse

I’m still new to R and I’ve been struggling with this issue for a couple of days. I found some solutions but I’m looking for a short code and I’d rather avoid a loop but so far that’s all I could come up with.
My data is the following :
[image]

The way I want it to look is the following:

```
Country    Year       ATM      POS  
France     2015        1       10    
France     2014        5        2    
France     2013       12        4     
France     2012        2       12
```

I haven’t found a short way to go about this so I broke it down into steps : I disabled headers, tried to make a vector out of the 1 row and I figured I’d do a pivot longer on the years first but I get an error on this :

```
ATM <- pivot_longer(data = dat, cols = dat[,2:6],names_to = "Year",values_to = headervector)
```

This would also require a loop for the POS part.
So, beyond fixing this, would there be a better approach that doesn’t require a loop?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Please `dput()` your `dat` and include in your post in order to help you!

Comment: @Duck is right; to be a little more specific, it will help us help you if you [edit] your question to include the output of the R command `dput(dat)` (or `dput(head(dat, n))` for some `n` if `dat` has many rows)

Comment: As others have requested, please use `dput(head(dat, ...))` to share a sample of what you're actually working with. However, this also seems very similar to another [recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62567018/1270695). R's `data.frame`s do not have multiple headers, so you need to `paste` multiple header levels together, as I did [in my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62567484/1270695).

Comment: Hi everyone, sorry if my message was confusing, I'm importing an xlsx file and I tried to split it with  header<- ("ATM","POS"). dat is the whole table. Pardon my ignorance, is dput to share the data or the code? Thank you for your help!

Comment: Read starting from the "country" line, make new column names after you've read the data in, then `melt`.

Comment: @A5C1D2H2I1M1N2O1R2T1, thanks, do you mean creating new column names on the row with country and years and making them unique? E.g. 2015.ATM, 2014.ATM,,,,2015.POS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this solution for any number of devices and years, compared to previous that handle only `ATM` and `POS`. This was done using your first data screen (Just load your excel file):

```
library(xlsx)
library(zoo)
library(reshape2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

#Data
dat <- structure(list(NA. = structure(1:2, .Label = c("Country", "France"
), class = "factor"), ATM = c(2015, 12), NA..1 = c(2014, 3), 
    NA..2 = c(2013, 4), NA..3 = c(2012, 6), NA..4 = c(2011, 7
    ), NA..5 = c(2010, 8), POS = c(2015, 9), NA..6 = c(2014, 
    9), NA..7 = c(2013, 12), NA..8 = c(2012, 11), NA..9 = c(2011, 
    56), NA..10 = c(2010, 78)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))

#Process names
names(dat)[1]<-'Country'
vecnames <- names(dat)[-1]
vecnames[which(grepl('NA',vecnames))]<-NA
vecnames <- na.locf(vecnames)
#Include year
vecnames2 <- dat[1,-1]
#Join
vecnames3 <- paste0(vecnames,'_',vecnames2)
#Assign names
names(dat)[-1]<-vecnames3
#Remove first row
dat <- dat[-1,]
#Melt data
melt.data <- melt(dat,id.vars = 'Country')
melt.data$variable<-as.character(melt.data$variable)
#Create columns
melt.data %>%
  separate(variable, c("Device", "Year"), "_") -> melt.data
#Output
DataG <- reshape(melt.data, idvar=c('Country','Year'), timevar='Device', direction="wide")
```

Output:

```
  Country Year value.ATM value.POS
1  France 2015        12         9
2  France 2014         3         9
3  France 2013         4        12
4  France 2012         6        11
5  France 2011         7        56
6  France 2010         8        78
```

Comment: thank for this, you actually anticipated something I noticed when I tried akrun's solution. I wouldn't work on more than 2 variables. I'm actually dealing with more and I'm also applying this code over several sheets. The first solution from A5C1D2H2I1M1N2O1R2T1 has worked so far. I'm probably going to use both :D

Comment: diferently from the NA..1, NA..2, etc, I have names with this pattern: ...5, ...6, ...7, etc. How to make the step vecnames[which(grepl('NA', vecnames))] <- NA?
I tried vecnames[which(grepl('...', vecnames))] <- NA, but all names changed to NA

Answer (score 2):

When you read your data in, use the option to specify starting the reading at the row where "Country" is found. For example, you would use `startRow` for `read.xlsx` -- not sure what you're using to read your Excel in. `...` represents any other arguments to `read.xlsx`.

```
x <- read.xlsx("your_file.xlsx", startRow = row_that_country_is_found, ...)
```

After you've done this, you may need to clean up your column names. The years might be read in as "X2015" or something similar. We'll assume that "x" now looks like this (random data):

```
x
#   Country      2015      2014      2013      2012       2011      2010
# 1       A 0.6883601 0.9199372 0.8996433 0.9644212 0.97940387 0.7564401
# 2       B 0.1572208 0.6507811 0.9444197 0.9420349 0.06572698 0.1445383
# 3       C 0.7599602 0.8948640 0.6020316 0.7315661 0.90211468 0.5831917
#          2015       2014      2013      2012      2011       2010
# 1 0.26770837 0.45293675 0.2363191 0.9718356 0.3290432 0.57801166
# 2 0.39756729 0.06007054 0.7108505 0.6843454 0.1690740 0.93432731
# 3 0.05011677 0.30123347 0.2633371 0.5079645 0.9527117 0.04442355
```

From here, you should rename your columns.

```
names(x) <- c("Country", paste(rep(c("ATM", "POS"), each = 6),
              names(x)[-1], sep = "_"))
```

Your names should now look like this:

```
names(x)
#  [1] "Country"  "ATM_2015" "ATM_2014" "ATM_2013" "ATM_2012" "ATM_2011"
#  [7] "ATM_2010" "POS_2015" "POS_2014" "POS_2013" "POS_2012" "POS_2011"
# [13] "POS_2010"
```

Then, you can `pivot_longer`, `separate` the names into multiple variables, and then `pivot_wider` to get your desired output.

```
x %>% 
  pivot_longer(-Country) %>% 
  separate(name, into = c("Type", "Year")) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = Type, values_from = value)
# # A tibble: 18 x 4
#    Country Year     ATM    POS
#    <chr>   <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#  1 A       2015  0.688  0.268 
#  2 A       2014  0.920  0.453 
#  3 A       2013  0.900  0.236 
#  4 A       2012  0.964  0.972 
#  5 A       2011  0.979  0.329 
#  6 A       2010  0.756  0.578 
#  7 B       2015  0.157  0.398 
#  8 B       2014  0.651  0.0601
# ... 
# 17 C       2011  0.902  0.953 
# 18 C       2010  0.583  0.0444
```

Comment: thanks so much for taking the time to give me such a thorough response. It's definitely working and I'll use it!

Answer (score 2):

We can also use `melt` from `data.table` which can also split by specifying any `patterns` in the column name.  The regex `^` matches the beginning of the column name followed by substring 'ATM' or 'POS'.  So, all the columns with 'ATM' will go into a single column 'ATM' while the 'POS' as next

```
library(data.table)
melt(setDT(df1), measure = patterns('^ATM', "^POS"), 
          value.name = c("ATM", "POS"), variable.name = "Year")
```

---

Or using `pivot_longer` with `names_sep` and specify the `names_to` so that it would split the columns at the delimiter `_`.   The order of `names_to` indicates where the 'year' and the value in that column (`.value`) would go into.  Here, we want the suffix of column name to be 'year' while the prefix (before the `_`) should get the values from that column

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    pivot_longer(cols = -Country, names_to = c(".value", "Year"), names_sep="_")
# A tibble: 18 x 4
#   Country Year     ATM    POS
#   <chr>   <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1 A       2015  0.688  0.268 
# 2 A       2014  0.920  0.453 
# 3 A       2013  0.900  0.236 
# 4 A       2012  0.964  0.972 
# 5 A       2011  0.979  0.329 
# 6 A       2010  0.756  0.578 
# 7 B       2015  0.157  0.398 
# 8 B       2014  0.651  0.0601
# 9 B       2013  0.944  0.711 
#10 B       2012  0.942  0.684 
#11 B       2011  0.0657 0.169 
#12 B       2010  0.145  0.934 
#13 C       2015  0.760  0.0501
#14 C       2014  0.895  0.301 
#15 C       2013  0.602  0.263 
#16 C       2012  0.732  0.508 
#17 C       2011  0.902  0.953 
#18 C       2010  0.583  0.0444
```

NOTE: Here it is based on the `_`.  So, it can handle any number of columns and it is not true about what is described in another post

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Country = c("A", "B", "C"), ATM_2015 = c(0.6883601, 
0.1572208, 0.7599602), ATM_2014 = c(0.9199372, 0.6507811, 0.894864
), ATM_2013 = c(0.8996433, 0.9444197, 0.6020316), ATM_2012 = c(0.9644212, 
0.9420349, 0.7315661), ATM_2011 = c(0.97940387, 0.06572698, 0.90211468
), ATM_2010 = c(0.7564401, 0.1445383, 0.5831917), POS_2015 = c(0.26770837, 
0.39756729, 0.05011677), POS_2014 = c(0.45293675, 0.06007054, 
0.30123347), POS_2013 = c(0.2363191, 0.7108505, 0.2633371), POS_2012 = c(0.9718356, 
0.6843454, 0.5079645), POS_2011 = c(0.3290432, 0.169074, 0.9527117
), POS_2010 = c(0.57801166, 0.93432731, 0.04442355)), class = "data.frame",
row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for this alternative solution. I tried the regex bit, because I liked how short the code was. However, the way the columns are renamed follows the opposite pattern : "ATM_2015" so the regex ^ doesn't work here. Would you have a suggestion?

Comment: @Lea7885. I assume the column names are `"ATM_2015"` instead of `"2015_ATM"` and that is how I showed.  If it s "2015_ATM", then your order of names_to  would be `c("Year", ".value")`