# R pivot_wider with multiple headers

Tags: r, tidyr, dataformat

I have a dataset that looks like this:

| ROI | Group | ID | Detections_per_Area |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Brainstem | A | JK002 | 0.0327285333827735 |
| Cerebellum | A | JK002 | 0.149208050073911 |
| Brainstem | A | JK002 | 0.0336959892253705 |
| Cerebellum | A | JK002 | 0 |

truncated: full dataset is here

```
structure(list(ROI = c("Brainstem", "Cerebellum", "Brainstem", 
"Cerebellum", "Brainstem", "Cerebellum", "Brainstem", "Cerebellum", 
"Brainstem", "Brainstem", "Brainstem", "Cerebellum", "Brainstem", 
"Brainstem", "Cerebellum", "Brainstem", "Brainstem", "Brainstem", 
"Cerebellum", "Cerebellum", "Brainstem", "Brainstem", "Brainstem", 
"Cerebellum", "Brainstem", "Brainstem", "Cerebellum", "Cerebellum", 
"Brainstem", "Brainstem", "Cerebellum", "Brainstem", "Brainstem", 
"Brainstem", "Cerebellum", "Cerebellum", "Brainstem", "Brainstem", 
"Brainstem", "Brainstem", "Cerebellum", "Brainstem", "Cerebellum"
), Group = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C"), ID = c("JK002", "JK002", "JK002", "JK002", 
"JK003", "JK003", "JK003", "JK003", "JK003", "JK004", "JK004", 
"JK004", "JK004", "JK005", "JK005", "JK005", "JK005", "JK006", 
"JK006", "JK006", "JK006", "JK006", "JK007", "JK007", "JK007", 
"JK008", "JK008", "JK008", "JK008", "JK008", "JK011", "JK011", 
"JK011", "JK011", "JK009", "JK009", "JK009", "JK009", "JK009", 
"JK010", "JK010", "JK010", "JK010"), Detections_per_area = c(0.0327285333827735, 
0.149208050073911, 0.0336959892253705, 0, 0.615965559353422, 
0.117064703241855, 0.171329148144879, 0, 0.131086542762028, 0.143700717389906, 
0.0590510074394172, 0, 0.0610284572370045, 0.358989653774582, 
0.113758644699529, 0.289455536567144, 0, 0.0355596373594045, 
0, 0.0661718135522336, 0.243313220125351, 0.373564943266101, 
0.591264576854053, 0.322774099148268, 0.725656324981598, 0.46343627586687, 
0, 0.227796467592069, 0.0876146804249713, 0.297011825126973, 
0.163792893059129, 0.336883295806429, 1.08791432091601, 0.370788052321182, 
1.49652281121774, 1.18495456669418, 3.36132331547411, 0.951628515574163, 
1.63575637052095, 0.408866067869112, 0, 1.47956381894319, 0.368780820643061
)), row.names = c(NA, -43L), class = "data.frame")
```

I'm trying to convert it to a Graphpad prism friendly format using R. This is the intended output, with values corresponding to the Detections_per_Area filled in(x). Annoyingly, Prism requires all groups to be the same size, regardless of the number of values, hence the nulls below.

|  | A | A | A | A | A | B | B | B | B | B | C | C | C | C | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | JK002 | JK002 | JK003 | JK004 | JK005 | JK001 | JK009 | JK010 | Null | Null | JK006 | JK007 | JK008 | JK011 | Null |
| Brainstem | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | Null | Null | x | x | x | x | Null |
| Cerebellum | x |  | x | x | x | x | x | x | Null | Null | x | x | x | x | Null |

Without the ID column, I have been able to generate the intended output using this code:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

Count<-data_source %>% count(ROI,Group, sort = TRUE)
highest = as.numeric(Count[1,'n'])
range = seq(1, highest)


  data_wide <- data_source %>% arrange(Group) %>% 
    group_by(ROI,Group) %>% mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% complete(rn = range) %>% 
    pivot_wider(
      names_from = c(Group, rn),
      values_from = Detections_per_area
)
  
names(data_wide) = gsub(pattern = "_.*", replacement = "", x = names(data_wide))
names(data_wide) = gsub(pattern = "ROI", replacement = "", x = names(data_wide))
```

This counts the largest group, and then generates row numbers that correspond to that, before pivoting.

Any advice on the best way to do this would be great, I thought about adding the ID to the name, and then removing that post-pivot, but haven't had any luck. This [previously asked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62613535/how-to-pivot-a-dataframe-on-a-two-level-header-in-r-code) did the opposite.

Comment: I see two rows for "Brainstem"+A+JK002 in the example.  But only once cell for these two values (in the wide format).  Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: I think the dataset (1st snipped) is out of sync with the code (2nd snippet).  The first has `Animal_Group` while the second has just `Group`.

Comment: Apologies, I've amended the original post, occasionally there are two values for a combination. Data has been synchronised and expected output has been updated.

Comment: I'm closer.  Just to clarify...  the desired output is a csv with *two* header rows?  The first row is "A, A, A, .., B, B.." and the second row is, "JK002, JK002, ..."

Comment: Are you sure the replicated IDs are correct?  It's tricky enough that "Brainstem+A+JK002" has two values.  It's even worse that  "Brainstem+A+JK003" has three values and "Cerebellum+A+JK003" has two.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the comments, I am not comfortable with how those IDs are reused.  From what I can tell, there's no good way to determine that "0.0327285333827735" (in the 1st row) should be associated with "0.149208050073911" (in the 3rd row) or "0" (in the 4th row).  The snippet below handles that correctly, assuming that the order is meaningful.  But I am really uncomfortable that "Brainstem+A+JK003" has three rows, while "Cerebellum+A+JK003" has two.  I strongly suggest that these IDs aren't reused.

I'm assuming that can be fixed.  And that's what this block simulates.  An ID can't be reused within a `ROI`-by-`Group` combination.

```r
data_source <-
  data_source |> 
  dplyr::group_by(ROI, Group, ID) |> 
  dplyr::slice_head() |> 
  dplyr::ungroup()
```

First the dataset is balanced so each ROIxGroup has the same number of rows.  The "Null" placeholder is used, as you specified above.

```r
# Determine structure (including the placeholders with "Null")
ds_skeleton <-
  data_source |> 
  dplyr::select(ROI, Group) |>
  dplyr::group_by(ROI, Group) |> 
  dplyr::mutate(
    rn = dplyr::row_number(Group),
  ) |> 
  dplyr::ungroup() |> 
  tidyr::complete(ROI, Group, rn)

# Order the observed data (with holes)
d2 <-
  data_source |> 
  dplyr::select(
    ROI, 
    Group, 
    ID, 
    y = Detections_per_area,    # Shorten to help with SO's narrow window.
  ) |>
  dplyr::group_by(ROI, Group) |> 
  dplyr::mutate(
    rn    = dplyr::row_number(Group),
  ) |> 
  dplyr::ungroup()
```

Then join the structure with the values.

```r
ds_long <-
  ds_skeleton |> 
  dplyr::left_join(d2, by = c("ROI", "Group", "rn")) |> 
  dplyr::mutate(
    ID  = dplyr::coalesce(ID, "Null"),
    # tag = paste(Group, rn, ID, sep = "_"),
    tag = sprintf(
      "%s_%03i_%s", # Pad the rn to accommodate "001" to "999"
      Group, rn, ID
    ),
    y  = dplyr::if_else(ID == "Null", "Null", as.character(y)),
  ) |> 
  dplyr::select(
    ROI,
    tag,
    y,
  )

# Pivot the values to the wide format
ds_wide <- 
  ds_long |> 
  tidyr::pivot_wider(
    id_cols     = "ROI",
    names_from  = "tag",
    values_from = "y"
  )
```

Finally the headers are constructed and stacked on top of the real data.  (There might be a more concise way to do with with [`dplyr::across()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/across.html).)

```r
# Construct the two header rows
pattern <- "^([A-Z])_\\d{3}_(.+)$" # Extracting info from tag
ds_header <- 
  ds_wide |> 
  dplyr::slice(0) |> # Drop the rows b/c we want only the column header
  tibble::add_row(ROI = "header") |>
  tidyr::pivot_longer(
    cols      = -"ROI",
    names_to  = "tag",
    values_to = "header_1"
  ) |>
  dplyr::mutate(
    header_1 = sub(pattern, "\\1", tag),
    header_2 = sub(pattern, "\\2", tag),
  ) |> 
  dplyr::select(-ROI) |>
  tidyr::pivot_longer(
    cols = c("header_1", "header_2"), names_to = "ROI") |>
  tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = "tag") |>
  dplyr::mutate(
    ROI = ""
  )

# Combine the headers with the data
ds_header  |> 
  dplyr::union_all(ds_wide)
```

To create a csv, pass `col_names = FALSE` to [`readr::write_csv()`](https://readr.tidyverse.org/reference/write_delim.html).

Comment: Appreciate this code, I realise it's no small feat! This works well when I coerce all ID's into a single value. This dataset refers to brains, with each ROI referring to a part of the brain. The ID represents a whole brain, hence sometimes we have multiple bits of the same part of the brain. Hence the duplicated ID's. Hence this is why I had the row numbers, so create an ID from the combination of ROI+group+ID+RN. It seems with the additional sections left in we have an issue with row numbers being allocated twice. IE, A_003_JK007 and A_003_JK006, which I suspect is an issue with the join.

Comment: I don't understand your last two sentences.  I don't think my code produces "A_003_JK007".  Isn't JK007 in Group B anyway?

Comment: Apologies, it is group B. I think I figured out that because there are these variable ID values, it's throwing out the synchronisation between ID's when the row numbers are produced, and hence we have a B_003_JK007 for the brainstem, and B_003_JK006 for the cerebellum. Hence why there is an issue with the way the tables are pivoting from ds_long to ds_wide